# How to assign imploded value from DB into Laravel blade template view?

Tags: php, laravel

I already imploded all my checkboxes into 1 value from `spoken_language[]` including 1 textfield value.

html

```
<div>
    {{ Form::checkbox('spoken_language[]', "English", array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
    <label>English</label>
</div>
<div>
    {{ Form::checkbox('spoken_language[]', "Bahasa Melayu", array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
    <label>Bahasa Melayu</label>
</div>
<div>
    {{ Form::checkbox('spoken_language[]', null, array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
    <label>Others</label>
    {{ Form::text('spoken_language[]', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

php

```
$request->merge(['spoken_language' => implode(',', (array) $request->get('spoken_language'))]);
```

The problem is how I can do the data binding into blade template view (checkbox and textfield) based on 1 value?

My collection

```
<?php

$user = DB::table('users')
    ->where("users.id", Auth::user()->id)
    ->first();

    return View::make('user.profile')->with('user', $user);
```

Like this example, I got these value `English,Bahasa Melayu,Urdu`, then I need to assign for each checkbox and Urdu in textfield. But if `English,Bahasa Melayu`, just checkbox only. Same goes to `Urdu`, goes to textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say `$storedSpokenLang` has the values retrieved in the database.

You can create a collection of user's saved languages and pass that to the blade view template.

```php
$spokenLang = collect(explode(',', $storedSpokenLang))->flip();
```

In the view, you can start from here:

```php
<div>
    {{ Form::checkbox(
           'spoken_language[]', 
           "English", 
           $spokenLang->has('English'), 
           array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
    <label>English</label>
</div>
<div>
    {{ Form::checkbox(
           'spoken_language[]',
           "Bahasa Melayu", 
           $spokenLang->has('Bahasa Melayu'),
           array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
    <label>Bahasa Melayu</label>
</div>
<div>
    {{ Form::checkbox(
           'spoken_language[]', 
           $spokenLang->except("English", "Bahasa Melayu", "")->isNotEmpty(),
           array('class' => 'form-check-input')) }}
    <label>Others</label>
    {{ Form::text(
           'spoken_language[]', 
           $spokenLang->except("English", "Bahasa Melayu", "")->keys()->implode(','),
           array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
</div>
```

Comment: I already updated my question with the collection. How to bind $spokenLang into view from there?

Comment: @MohammadNurdin in your `View::make()->with()->with('spokenLang', $spokenLang);`